# How to accept data while sending in my python script?

Tags: python, sockets

i have this written a server side script and a client script to send messages to each other but each script can only send its message after it has received one,im pretty new to this and im wondering if anyone can help me out so that they can send and receive messages at will.
Any help is appreciated.
Server script : http://pastebin.com/fnJ1S71y
Client Script : http://pastebin.com/Kiq0dXKc

Comment: related: http://scotdoyle.com/python-epoll-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time for a good answer, but the short of it is that you want to use select.select() to see if there's anything going on either on your socket or on stdin.